# Client side javascript doesn't find my url

Tags: javascript, node.js, client-server

I would like to develop a client server side with nodejs and javascript/jquery but I am stuck.
I have a big form, user submits and data are send to `/getData` url and that works perfectly. But my problem now it's when I want to get those data from `/getData` to my client side.

This is my client file:

```
var client = {};
client.start = function () {

    client.getData();
};

client.cb_get = function () {

    var data={};

    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {   

        data= JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        alert("We get the data" + JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));
        client.chart(data);

    } else {

        alert("Sorry this page is not allow without processing any form");
    }
};


client.get = function(req, cb) {   
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", req, true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = cb;
    xhr.send();
};


client.getData= function () { 

    var req="http://localhost:3000/getData";
    client.get(req,client.cb_get);
};

client.chart= function (data) {
  //Display data as charts using jquery in an other html page.
};

window.onload = setTimeout(client.start, 1);

HTMLElement.prototype.has_class = function (c) 
{
    return this.className.indexOf(c) >= 0;
};
```

But I have a 404 error all the time and I don't know why.

my server file :

```
var express = require('express')
    bodyParser =require("body-parser");
    routes= require('./router.js');

var app= express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));
//Here we are configuring express to use body-parser as middle-ware.
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));


//define our routes
app.get('/', routes.index); //open home page
app.get('/simulation', routes.simulation);
app.get('/chartData', routes.chartData);

app.post('/getData', routes.getData);

//In case of malicious attacks or mistyped URLs
app.all('*', function(req, res){
  res.send(404);
})

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {

  var host = server.address().address
  var port = server.address().port

  console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port)

})
```

my router file:

```
module.exports.index= function(req, res){

    fs.readFile('index.html', function(err, page) {
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        res.write(page);
        res.end();
    });

};

module.exports.simulation= function(req, res){

     fs.readFile('simulation.html', function(err, page) {
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        res.write(page);
        res.end();
    });
};


module.exports.chartData= function(req,res) {

     fs.readFile('chartPage.html', function(err, page) {
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        res.write(page);
        res.end();

    });
};

module.exports.getData= function(req,res) {

    var data= {};
    data= req.body;
    res.send(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));
    console.log(req.body);    

};
```

So where I am wrong?
Moreover, when I submit, my `/getdata` page opens (normal due to `action= /getData` specified in my form tag) but I want to open directly my html page with charts. How can I do that?

Sorry guys for my long post, but I really need help.

Comment: I'd use lowercase for URL's, not camelcase ?

Comment: I always use camel case...changed it but my problem is still there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your ajax request does

```
xhr.open("GET", "http://localhost:3000/getData", true);
```

your route listens for

```
app.post('/getData', routes.getData);
```

notice how you send a `GET` request and listen for a `POST` request, it's not the same thing, so you end up in the 404 route instead.

You either have to change the ajax request, and send a `POST` request, or the route and listen for a `GET` request.

Comment: Hey thank you for you quick response! I have changed my ajax request by xhr.open("POST", "req", true);  but now my browser is running until it tells me Safari couldn't open the page!

Comment: Then try returning something simple in the route, like `res.end('{"test":"test"}');`

Comment: And try logging `this` in the `cb_get` function, something tells it's not the XHR object, but I'm not quite sure ?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly why, but generally when the browser is hanging, it's hitting the route but just not getting a response back so it just keeps trying until it time outs. When it's not hitting the route, you'd go straight for the catch-all route.